# I want to import gmail contacts but it was throwing an error when I am trying to fetch data from Contact

Tags: c#, gmail

I want to import gmail contacts and for that I am trying to run following code

```
public static DataSet GetGmailContacts(string App_Name, string Uname, string UPassword)
{

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn C2 = new DataColumn();
    C2.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
    C2.ColumnName = "EmailID";
    dt.Columns.Add(C2);

    RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings(App_Name, Uname, UPassword);
    rs.AutoPaging = true;
    ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs);
    Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();
    foreach (Contact t in f.Entries)
    {
        foreach (EMail email in t.Emails)
        {
            DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
            dr1["EmailID"] = email.Address.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
        }
    }
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    return ds;

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DataSet ds = GetGmailContacts("MyNetwork Web Application!", txtgmailusername.Text, txtpassword.Text);
    gvmails.DataSource = ds;
    gvmails.DataBind();
}
```

But it is throwing an exception:

> Execution of request returned unexpected result: http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/fullMovedPermanently

When I am trying to use

```
foreach (Contact t in f.Entries)
```

Answer (score 1):

Install-Package Google.GData.Contacts from your nuget pm your issue will be resolved